# Specify arg. value in function definition

Tags: c++

Am I missing something completely. How can we simply put the value in definition line of the function. If so, whats the point of passing values if we have predefined it.
Something like this :

```
node( unsigned char c = 0, int i = 0)
```

Strange thing is this code runs, and executes properly. (Visual Studio 2010).

Is it something related to const function? But then there is no const mentioned.

Or something like this :

```
void traverse(string code="") const
```

But the earlier definition was not const'd.

Comment: You mean *default arguments*? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> node( unsigned char c = 0, int i = 0)

These are default arguments. This means that you can write `node()` in some body of code instead of `node(0,0)`, `node('x')` instead of `node('x',0)`. There's nothing to stop you from using `node('x', 2)`. In this case `node` will receive `'x'` and `2` as the values for `c` and `i`.